# Django: Changing text of "AM" and "PM"

Tags: python, django, parsing

I want to be able to use Python's `strptime` on times like `9:00p`, where the `p` stands for PM.

It seems like my closest bet is the `%p` switch:

http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime

Problem is, it parses only `pm` or `PM`. I want it to accept `p`.

The documentation say it uses "Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM". Is there a way for me to change my "locale’s equivalent" to be `p` and `a`?

Comment: You say you can't pre-process? A code snippet would be useful.

Comment: You need to show code before we can answer anything, so i'm down-voting your question for now.

Comment: I think the point everyone's making here, is that regardless of what other code/packages are in the mix, at *some point* you must be dealing with your *own* code. How else are you calling `strptime` in the first place. So at this point, right before `strptime`, do the replace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately both the short and long time formats in Windows only support `tt` for A.M. or P.M., there does not appear to be a way to change that.

Can you not pre-process the string and use `.replace('p', 'pm').replace('a', 'am')` ?

Comment: I can't pre-process, because the processing is done in `django` code. A Linux-only solution would be helpful too.

Comment: @RamRachum, where does this string come from that you are not able to intercept it on the way the the `strptime` call?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are wanting `strptime` to parse everything when you are probably better off thinking of it as a convenience function. Changing the "locale equivalent" is a good way to make mysterious code and have other things (like `strftime`) break.

You'd do better to replace `9:00p` with `9:00pm` in the string *first* and then pass it to `strptime`. You'll probably want to check for reasonableness in your substitution, for example "Thursp" should not become "Thurspm".

Answer (score -1):

You *can* pre-process it. You *can* alter code that's part of django core.

Worst case scenario, you can use subclasses or even monkey-patch. If you decide to show some code instead, we'll be glad to point the way forward.